# Recording with Camera2 API without using MediaRecorder

Tags: android, android-camera2

In my Android application, I need to capture camera images continuously and keep sending them over the network for remote viewing.

I have looked at `Camera2` recording sample. It seems this code relies on `MediaRecorder` class. However, in my case, I just need to capture raw images as fast as possible, encode it in a specific way, and send it over the network.

Looks like the central concept of Camera2 API is that it requires a `Surface` class. Is it possible to create a pseudo-surface class and somehow attach to it such that the images can be captured continuously? Or, is there a better way? Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an ImageReader if you just want ByteBuffers of uncompressed YUV data.

If you do want to encode the frames before sending them over the network, you can use a MediaCodec (which can give you a Surface) connected to the camera to efficiently encode the frames before sending them to the destination. That's assuming the kind of encoding you want is available on the device.

The latter is what most video chat apps do, whenever possible.

Comment: Thank you very much Eddy. MediaCodec seems to be what I needed.